# Getting HTTP error 500 after migrating a website

Tags: migration, 500-internal-error

I recently migrated my wordpress website and now I am getting http error 500.
The debugg log says:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function update_option() in /home/sweetsixsteen/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sweetsixsteen/public_html/wp-settings.php(98): require()
#1 /home/sweetsixsteen/public_html/wp-config.php(110): require_once('/home/sweetsixs...')
#2 /home/sweetsixsteen/public_html/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/sweetsixs...')
#3 /home/sweetsixsteen/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/sweetsixs...')
#4 /home/sweetsixsteen/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/sweetsixs...')
#5 {main}
  thrown in /home/sweetsixsteen/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3
[16-Sep-2017 01:23:33 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function update_option() in /home/sweetsixsteen/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sweetsixsteen/public_html/wp-settings.php(98): require()
#1 /home/sweetsixsteen/public_html/wp-config.php(110): require_once('/home/sweetsixs...')
#2 /home/sweetsixsteen/public_html/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/sweetsixs...')
#3 /home/sweetsixsteen/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/sweetsixs...')
#4 /home/sweetsixsteen/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/sweetsixs...')
#5 {main}
  thrown in /home/sweetsixsteen/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3
```

I would appreciate some help as I am new to this and have no idea what might be wrong. Is it fixable?

Answer (score 2):

Given these errors are all being generated by WP core, there might be a corrupt install (a file/files only partially copied)

Download the matching WP install and manually upload the files above throwing errors over the top